Export Excel using EPPlus and Web API
I am trying to export the data from the database through export Excel method using EPPlus. But I am unable to export, it returns type error  or undocumented. I am using EPPlus version 4.5.2.1. I need to enter the parameters in Swagger, I don't know why I need to enter the parameters? Is there somebody will help me to solve this?
[HttpPost("Export")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Export(OverallModel export)
{
    var tasks = await _task.OverallModel.ToListAsync();

    using (var package = new ExcelPackage())
    {
        var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
        worksheet.Cells["A1"].Value = "Id";
        worksheet.Cells["B1"].Value = "Date";
        worksheet.Cells["C1"].Value = "Category";
        worksheet.Cells["D1"].Value = "Actual Date";
        worksheet.Cells["E1"].Value = "Assigned To";
        worksheet.Cells["F1"].Value = "Task";
        worksheet.Cells["G1"].Value = "Duration";
        worksheet.Cells["H1"].Value = "Status";
        worksheet.Cells["I1"].Value = "Priority";

        int row = 2;

        foreach(var task in tasks)
        {
            worksheet.Cells[row, 1].Value = task.Id;
            worksheet.Cells[row, 2].Value = task.Date;
            worksheet.Cells[row, 3].Value = task.category;
            worksheet.Cells[row, 4].Value = task.actualDate;
            worksheet.Cells[row, 5].Value = task.assignedTo;
            worksheet.Cells[row, 6].Value = task.task;
            worksheet.Cells[row, 7].Value = task.timeTaken;
            worksheet.Cells[row, 8].Value = task.status;
            worksheet.Cells[row, 9].Value = task.priority;
            row++;
        }

        worksheet.Cells["A:I"].AutoFitColumns();

        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        package.SaveAs(stream);
        stream.Position = 0;

        string excelName = "Tasks-{DateTime.Now:yyyyMMddHHmmss}.xlsx";
        return File(stream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", excelName);
    }
}


Hi @Vengat Ramanan, what is your target framework? You tagged asp.net core but EPPlus version 4.5.2.1 does not support asp.net core.

@Rena my framework version is 8.0

Hi @Vengat Ramanan, I test your code with .net 8 and EPPlus 4.5.2.1 , it works fine. What do you men for need to enter the parameters in Swagger? Do you mean why you need add parameter in body for the OverallModel? You add a useless parameter in your Export action (OverallModel export) so that the Swagger will generate the model example.

Can you share your model design of OverallModel and the corresponding database table design? Ensure OverallModel properties (e.g., task.Id, task.Date, etc.) align with the database structure. Also you need confirm that each cell value matches EPPlus-supported data types
